# Waveshare Display on ESP32 has weird graphic glitches

Tags: display, esp32

I am trying to pass an image to the display through the GxEPD module. I tested the display and its working fine with an example sketch.

I am using a WEMOS LOLIN32 and a 7,5" B/W Waveshare display.

When I add any other image after converting it to hex values, this happens:

This is the image in GIMP:

[image]

And this is what the display shows:

[image]

As you can see, the display shows the image glitched a lot. It looks a lot like each "row" of a few pixels is mirrored horizontal. The question here is: Why? All I did was converting the image in GIMP to .xbm, taking the content, stripping whitespace, pasting the Arduino syntax around the code and replacing the example file with this one.

Comment: looks like a mixup between LSB and MSB encoding

Comment: yea, i thought so too, but i dont know how i can effectively solve this - i could include this in my python script im using for formating the code, but i wish there was a simpler fix for that

Comment: looks like poor software rescaling to me, are you sure the resolution is correct?

Comment: i changed the size of the image to exactly the pixels that were named in the article description - it should definetly be right, i tried making the image a few pixels smaller to see what happen, but that turned the image into an unreadable mess even more.